# How to fire a function after another one has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions, triggered by the same click event:

```
$(".mydiv").click(function() {

// Code 1

});
```

and

```
$(".mydiv").click(function() {

// Code 2

});
```

I want both blocks of code to fire on the same click event, but I want code 2 to fire immediately after code 1 has completed. What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call one function something like foo() and then at the end of code 1 just say foo() ?

Answer (score 4):

"Code 1" and "Code 2" should be function calls. You can then do:

```
$('.mydiv').on('click', function(){
  code1();
  code2();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var func1 = function() {
  //code here


  func2();
}

var func2 = function() {
  //code here
};

$('.mydiv').click(func1);
```

NOTE: This won't work if you're performing asynchronous operations in func1 and want func2 to fire when those operation(s) complete.

Comment: **+1** for not violating the K.I.S.S. theory.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* set a callback to your first function like this example:

```
$(".mydiv").click(function() {
    myfirstFunction(function(){
        myLastFunction();
    });
});

myfirstFunction = function(callback) {
    // do your thing
    // and at the end...
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

[Click here to see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNEDj/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but I think this clearly violates the K.I.S.S. theory.

Comment: @DevlshOne It depends on the need here. If you need to work with asynchronous it can be a good tip. But this is just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Code is executed from top to bottom , so it should be :

```
$(".mydiv").click(function() {

// Code 1
// Code 2
});
```